# Import data from URL into excel

Tags: vba, excel

I am new to excel vba. I have data in website URL. I need to import into workbook sheet. I am able to create sheet and import, whereas I want to import into particular sheet.

This one work

```
Sub Test()
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    strURL = "https://www.nseindia.com/products/dynaContent/equities/equities/histscrip.jsp?symbolCode=1693&symbol=AXISBANK&symbol=axisbank&segmentLink=17&symbolCount=1&series=ALL&dateRange=1month&fromDate=&toDate=&dataType=PRICEVOLUMEDELIVERABLE"
    Application.Workbooks.Open (strURL)
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

But following modification into code is not working. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
Sub OpenCSV()
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
strURL = "https://www.nseindia.com/products/dynaContent/equities/equities/histscrip.jsp?symbolCode=1693&symbol=AXISBANK&symbol=axisbank&segmentLink=17&symbolCount=1&series=ALL&dateRange=1month&fromDate=&toDate=&dataType=PRICEVOLUMEDELIVERABLE"
Worksheets("dump").Range("A1").Select
With Selection
    .Open (strURL)
End With
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a querytable and specify the target sheet and range.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub testing()
    Dim qt As QueryTable
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    Const URL As String = "https://www.nseindia.com/products/dynaContent/equities/equities/histscrip.jsp?symbolCode=1693&symbol=AXISBANK&symbol=axisbank&segmentLink=17&symbolCount=1&series=ALL&dateRange=1month&fromDate=&toDate=&dataType=PRICEVOLUMEDELIVERABLE"
    Set qt = ws.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="URL;" & URL, Destination:=ws.Range("A1"))

    With qt
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = True
        .FieldNames = True
        .WebSelectionType = xlSpecifiedTables
        .WebTables = 1
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
End Sub
```